# Refreshing the page even if error message is shown

Tags: forms, submit, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-contour

I'm using umbraco CMS and have a problem with my form.

I've added error messagges if some of the fields are empty.
If you click on "submit" the page is refreshing, and you need to scroll down again to the form section in order to view the error messages.

I did a lot of changes in the form section (design) but can't find a solution to the problem.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [new UmbracoForms](http://umbraco.com/products-and-support/forms/) implementation?

This sounds to me like a script or style issue. You should track when the user has submitted the form and after the submission (if there are errors present) scroll down to form section.

Your second option would be submitting form through AJAX, but new UmbracoForms don't currently support it: [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549096/new-umbracoforms-not-contour-ajax-call).

Comment: Thanks!I'm using the new UmbracoForms

Comment: You're welcome. :) Basically, new UmbracoForms are quite limited in this section. We all [in Umbraco community] hope this will improve soon enough. In the meantime, you will have to build your own custom logic.

Comment: Ye.. I spending so much time just looking for the right places to every element..

Comment: I would suggest adding additional markup element above <form> (or use existing) and make your position on page "jump" to this part on form submit. From a layman's point of view, of course. Also, [anchors](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html) could also prove useful here.

Comment: Thanks! where I need to add the javascript code for the jumping?

Comment: You could either add it on the page itself, as inline javascript, or to your script that is being loaded with the page. But, you would need a "flag" telling you that the form was unsuccessfully validated. Perhaps adding something in your URL query string?